# For how many integers $a$ does this equation have three solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> For how many integers $a$ does the equation $(x^2-a^2 ) \sqrt{(5-x)}=0$
>    have three different solutions?

The options were: $10, 9, 8, $other.

I say **other.**

No matter what, $\sqrt{5-x} = 0$ always has one solutions.

Then it is remaining to solve:

$x^2 - a^2 = 0 \implies x^2 = a^2 \implies x = \pm a$, which is true for any $a$ really, except $a=0$.

Comment: "No matter what"... unless $|a|\gt 5$, in which case the main equation cannot have $\pm a$ as solutions if we do not allow complex numbers.

Comment: Rewrite $x^2-a^2$ as $(x+a)(x-a)$, and then reconsider your answer.

Comment: @abiessu, even if $a = 3$ then, $x^2 = 9$, which gives $x = (-3, 3)$

Comment: @Amad27: if $a=3$ then $|a|<5$, which is not what I was referring to...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

1. Solutions should be integers
2. Imaginary numbers do not come to picture.

We need three distinct solutions.

Consider $(x^2-a^2)=0\implies x=\pm a$ if $a\ne0$, else two solutions will be $0$.

Consider $\sqrt{5-x}=0\implies x\le5$, else $\sqrt{5-x}$ goes imaginary.

If $a=5$, then two solutions will be $5$, one contributed by $\sqrt{5-x}=0$ and one by $(x^2-5^2)=0$.

Hence the only integer options left with us are $\pm 1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4$, that is, 8 choices for $a$.

---

However, if imaginary numbers are allowed, all values of $a$ except $0,5$ works.

Comment: @But, if $a$ is any integer different from $0$ and $5$ we have anyway three integer solutions, also if the square root is imaginary.

Comment: @EmilioNovati, true, but I ruled them out since its a precalc question. I hope its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

For $\sqrt{5-x}$  to be real $x\le5$

So values x can hold are 1,2,3,4,5 
For $(x^2-a^2) = 0 $ x should be $\pm a$
But if it becomes $\pm 5$ there will be only two solutions because one 5 will be contributed from $\sqrt{5-x} = 0 $ hence the required numbers are  $\pm 1, \pm 2 , \pm3 , \pm4 $